# Override View id

Tags: android

Is it possible to override view id or to make some kind of pointer reference to another view id?

I have the following scenario:
An activity I don't have the source code for has some hard coded `findViewById()` like this:

```
class MyActivit extends Activity {

 // Will be called after setContentView()
 @Override
 public void onContentChanged(){
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foo);
        textView.setText("Foo");
    }

}
```

As already said I can't change this code. So this class assumes that there is a TextView with the id `R.id.foo` in the layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <TextView id="@id/foo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

However, my current layouts have some code that looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <TextView id="@id/other" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The problem is obvious: With my layout file on the `MyActivity` I get an `NullPointerException`.

Is there a way to say that `R.id.foo` is "forwarding" / "pointing" to `R.id.other`? I want to avoid changing all my layout files. I already tried doing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item name="foo" type="id" format="reference">@id/other</item>
  <item name="other" type="id" />
</resources>
```

but that doesn't work. Is there a way to make such a "forwarding" in xml?

Comment: but before changing the reference, wouldn't you need to change the name of the activity xml in `setContentView()`?

Comment: Yeah, that's just a hypothetical example. Don't worry about the layout.  Actually the `findViewById()` is hardcoded in `onContentChanged()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContentChanged() ... I have change that  in my question to avoid confussion

Comment: Maybe it is better to extending this activity (if it is not declared as final) and override needed methods for your specific implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct solution. Is possible to do that in xml, I just made it the wrong way around in my question. The correct solution is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item name="foo" type="id" />
  <item name="other" type="id">@id/foo</item> <!-- means R.id.other = R.id.foo -->
</resources>
```

So `R.id.other` gets assigned the value of `R.id.foo`. So `R.id.other` is some kind of alias for `R.id.foo`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to do, before the activity is called, `yourView.setId(R.id.foo)`?

If that is the case, then all your other text views will be replaced and set to `yourView.setId(R.id.foo)`

Totally not a big fan of this fix... it's a weird problem you have. It may be a courtesy of bad design...?

Comment: Didn't get that ... What do you mean with "before the activity is called"?